# Change tab spacing on existing HTML document in Netbeans

Tags: html, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have inherited an HTML document which has been formatted with 2 spaces instead of tab indentations.

Is there a way in Netbeans (8.1) to replace all the indents with tabs instead of the 2 spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto `Tools -> Options` choose `Editor` tab, then select `On Save` tab, now select language `HTML`, there you can choose `Reformat` and `Remove Trailing White Spaces` after that choose `Apply -> Ok`.

Or you can hit <kbd>Alt + Shift + F</kbd> in Windows OS, or right click on `HTML` document choose `Format` option this will Reformat your code with `tab`s

Answer (score 0):

In Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting there you select

- Languaje: HTML
- Category: Tabs And Indents

Uncheck the "Use All Languajes Settings" and now you are able to modify the settings according to what you want.

---